# I'm trying to send email with the mailer and nestjs

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I'm trying to send email with the mailer and nestjs. The error it gives:

```
ErrorError: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. learn more at
535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials w5sm528203qko.34 - gsmtp
```

Installed the module following this [link](https://nest-modules.github.io/mailer/docs/mailer.html)

My **app.module.ts** I add:

```
MailerModule.forRoot({
      transport: 'smtps://rafaelribeirosouza86@gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com',
      defaults: {
        from: '"nest-modules" <rafaelribeirosouza86@gmail.com>',
      }
    })
```

My service:

```
await this.mailerService
      .sendMail({
        to: createCatDto.email, // list of receivers
        from: 'rafaelribeirosouza86@gmail.com', // sender address
        subject: 'Novo password', // Subject line
        text: 'Sua nova senha é:'+createCatDto.senhaNormal // plaintext body
        //html: '<b>welcome</b>', // HTML body content
      })
      .then(() => {})
      .catch((error) => {console.log("Error"+error)});
```

Remembering that nestjs is an api for android and in the api I'm trying to send email

Comment: have you read this https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/

Comment: thank you @MicaelLevi